# opencv, Linking C static library ../lib/armeabi-v7a/liblibjpeg.a

Tags: android, macos, opencv, android-ndk, makefile

I'm compiling openCV on Mac (64-bits). When I compile using "make " I get this error

"Linking C static library ../lib/armeabi-v7a/liblibjpeg.a". Don't know what this error is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the makefile, replace

```
-llibjpeg
```

with

```
-ljpeg
```

In NDK/*nix linker, the "lib" prefix is attached by default.

Comment: Won't you please provide some more info, as I'm compiling with cMake and unable to fine -llibjpeg. I'm compiling openCV with android_crystax on Mac OSX, but unable to spot this static linking